# Is it useful to consider a categorical features into a `polynomial` or `linear model`?

Tags: predictive-modeling

In Titanic dataset, i have a dataset containing **Categorical** features (such as **Cabin**, **Embark** and **Sex**).

[image]

I need to build a **linear** or **polynomial** model with multiple variables to predict `Survive`. I wish to consider **Categorical** features as well. Let's say, i can replace all categorical values with a respected numerical value. For example about `Sex` column, I can replace: `1` with `male` and `2` with `female`

My question is:

Is it useful to consider a categorical features into a `polynomial` or `linear model`?